# is mingw malloc using calloc as it appears to be as slow as calloc

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I recently learned the hard-way that on linux `calloc` is not nearly as fast as `malloc` this may have been exacerbated by the program rarely using anything more than the first 0.1% of memory allocated. After switching to `malloc` suddenly my code was running much faster (over 100 times faster!).

On windows (compiled with mingw) however I notice that the code remains slow when switching from `calloc` to `malloc`, in-fact their is no noticeable difference in running time! Is it that mingw calls calloc instead of `malloc`? How would I find out, I tried strace.exe under cygwin but that didn't show a call to `malloc` or `calloc`.

Perhaps `malloc`s are just very slow on windows.

Comment: I do notice that when I decrease the amount of memory allocated from 1MB to around 8KB, malloc appears faster than calloc so perhaps it is windows that is slow to allocate memory.

Comment: Try calling `malloc()` to allocate a large chunk of memory, initialize it to something other than zero, `free()` it, and call `malloc()` again with the same size. Check the returned address using `printf("%p", ...)`. It's likely, but not certain, that you'll get the same memory address both times. If the addresses are the same and the memory from the second allocation isn't all zeros, then it's not using `calloc()`.

Comment: I did as you suggested and I could allocate another meg at the same address and the first char was set to zero so it looks like windows is zeroing the memory, is it possible to have windows not do this?